# React infinite-react-carousel package error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install

when I type `"npm i infinite-react-carousel --save"` in the terminal I get:

```
"npm ERR! code ERESOLVE 

"npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree"
```

What is the cause? How can i solve this? I tried;
`--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps`. But it didn't work.

I was expecting to install `infinite-react-carousel` package.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal as administrator, then try putting the command in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already tried this, but I used same command and it worked for me. Maybe you typed this incorrectly, try again using below command.

```bash
  npm install infinite-react-carousel --legacy-peer-deps
```